# generate unique array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a such problem which I couldn't solve in a good manner. My solution needs too much time and loop uses catastrophically big memory. So I need a help.

I have 3 mysql tables.

### Gorups

- group_id
- group_name

### games

- game_id
- game_name

### questions

- question_id
- game_id
- question_name
- question_text

### question_groups

- question_id
- group_id
- order

The problem is following.

The questions are asked in following manner. One after another. The problem is that I need to make a shufle funnction in php in such way, that I will assign each question to each group in that way, that for example the first question for each group will be unique, and no 2 or 3 groups will get the same question, the same for second, third, .....tenth question.

What is the most optimal solution for this?

Should I use somehow mysql function for that or php?

Comment: I don't understand this question... can you give a worked example to help explain it?

Comment: @Mark Byers If I understand it correctly, the table question_groups needs to be populated, based on entries in the questions table.  I have no idea how group_id is supposed to be related.

Comment: As I told on my comment for the answer lower, the game is in such way that there is 10 rounds, for 10 groups with 10 questions. 
in each round the groups gets questions and the questions should be assigned in a way that each group gets the question that is not given to another group on the same round and is not already answered. And this table of sequense should be defined beforehand.
we should have a table 10X10 , with numbers 1-10 and in each row and column we don't have duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this issue is to define a unique constraint/index for the `question_id` column in `QUESTIONS_GROUPS`.  This constrains the data so that the value can only occur once in the entire table - a user would receive a unique constraint error if they attempted to add a duplicate `question_id` value.

Here's the statement you'd need to use to define the constraint in MySQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_idx BTREE ON QUESTION_GROUPS(question_id)
```

### Edit:

If you need to support a question being asked only once per round, I'm assuming that the `QUESTION_GROUPS.order` column is what the round value is.  Assuming that's correct, add the `order` column to the unique constraint/index to ensure unique pairs of values:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_idx BTREE ON QUESTION_GROUPS(question_id, order)
```

If you made the `group_id` and `question_id` columns to be the composite primary key for the table, it won't work for your requirements because it would allow the `question_id` column value to be duplicated.

I would also define that the `QUESTION_GROUPS.group_id` not be allowed to be NULL, otherwise you could assign a question to a NULL (non-existent) group and would have to update the existing record or delete & recreate it with a valid group.

Reference:

- [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: the problem is that the same question shouldnt be given on the first round to more than one group. 
game is with rounds 
10 groups 10 rounds 10 questions. I understand that I can make composite index, the problem is the php side, How to generate right insert.....

Comment: @DR.GEWA: The right insert?  Insert what you like, the unique constraint will tell you if you attempt to associate a question either more than once or more than once per round, depending on your business rules...

Comment: it's not only about the 2 times the same question to the same person, but also not to giving the same to 2 different persons.....